# How to explain the result to this Java enum function?

Tags: java, enums

**Given**

```
public enum Title {

MR("Mr."), MRS("Mrs."), MS("Ms.");

private final String title;

private Title(String t) {
    title = t;
}

public String format(String last, String first) {
    return title + "" + first + "" + last;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Title.MR.format("Doe","John"));
}
```

---

Does anyone know how to explain this ? Keep in mind the code is not fully complete. This happens to be a question from a book. The Answer to this question is Mr. John Doe.

Thanks

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: What does the book say?  This is really simple code ...

Comment: Actually, the answer would be `Mr.JohnDoe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, consider reading [**this**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html), in order to understand **what** is an [`Enum`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html), **how** it works, and **when** you should use it.

Now, concerning your `Enum` example, you are declaring an `Enum`erated type with three possible values: `MR`, `MRS`, and `MS`. `Enum`s, just like `Class`es, can have **methods** and **constructors**. In your example, `Title` has a single argument constructor -- which stores a description of the `Title` --, and a method that basically prepends the description to a given name -- the `format` method.

So, when you invoke `Title.MR.format("Doe","John"))`, first you get an instance of the `MR` `Title`, and then you invoke the `format` method, which returns **`Mr.John Doe`**.

Also note that only one instance of each `Title` is created, so that invoking `Title.MR` several times will always return the same objet.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rewriting of the original snippet from an `enum` to a `class`; it captures *most* what the original snippet does. I also rewrote the string concatenation part using [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for instructional purposes.

```
public class Title {

    public static final Title MR = new Title("Mr.");
    public static final Title MRS = new Title("Mrs.");
    public static final Title MS = new Title("Ms.");

    private final String title;
    private Title(String t) { title = t; }

    public String format(String last, String first) {
        return String.format("%s %s %s", title, first, last);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Title.MR.format("Doe","John"));
        // prints "Mr. John Doe"
    }
}
```

Note the similarity with the `enum` code. But note also that this version is much more verbose. It's important that you know enough Java to understand why this version works the way it is. Once you do, understanding the `enum` version is simple: `enum` are classes in Java. It is not as "simple" a type as the C/C++ counterpart.

#### References

- [Java Language Guide/Enums](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)
- [JLS 8.9 Enums](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9)

#### Related questions

On Java vs C++ difference:

- [Difference of Enum between java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080681/difference-of-enum-between-java-and-c)
- [Enum in Java. Advantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages)

On various `enum` usage:

- [Java Enum Item Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054247/java-enum-item-description)
- [Get enum by its inner field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780129/get-enum-by-its-inner-field)
- [Can I add a function to enums in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457076/can-i-add-a-function-to-enums-in-java) (*ABSOLUTELY!*)
- [Is there a a C-like way to get item number from enum in java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765687/is-there-a-a-c-like-way-to-get-item-number-from-enum-in-java)

  - (Yes, but why when there are so much better alternatives!?

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Chapter 6: Enums and Annotations*

  - *Item 30: Use enums instead of `int` constants*
  - *Item 31: Use instance fields instead of ordinals*
  - *Item 32: Use `EnumSet` instead of bit fields*
  - *Item 33: Use `EnumMap` instead of ordinal indexing*

#### API links

- [`java.lang.Enum`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)
- [`java.lang.EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/EnumSet.html)
- [`java.util.EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)

Comment: Very descriptive. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the question is how the result is fabricated, here's the source code with some comments:

```
public enum Title { // Declare an enum named Title

// Declare the enumerations with parameters that correspond with the constructor
MR("Mr."), MRS("Mrs."), MS("Ms.");

private final String title; // Declare String attribute (has null value at this point)

private Title(String t) { // enum constructor which accepts a String
    title = t; // Initialize title String with parameter t
}
// format method which accepts last and first Strings and returns a String
public String format(String last, String first) {
    // return is a String constructed from title first and last Strings.
    return title + "" + first + "" + last;
}
}

// Main method which is triggered when the class is run
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Output to console a call to the MR enum of Title with parameters Doe and John
    System.out.println(Title.MR.format("Doe","John"));
}
```

Hope that makes the code clearer.